# Test if child component is being conditionally rendered after toggle method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

This is a Vue component that has a toggle function, which hides or shows a detail child component for each item in the rendered v-for list from an array.

I would like to test this functionality with Jest. More specifically when the conditions for ListDetails is true:

```
<ListDetails
   v-if="currentIndex >= 0 && currentIndex === index"
/>
```

I would like to check if ListDetails is being rendered.

This is what I got so far. I've tried different scenarios bu all if them seem to return false.

```
it("check if child is rendered after toggle method", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ErrandsListTable);
    wrapper.vm.toggleExpanded(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(ListDetails).exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.vm.currentIndex).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0);

    // expect(wrapper.find(<ListDetails />).exists()).toBeTruthy();
    // expect(wrapper.find(ListDetails).exists()).toBeTruthy();

    // expect(wrapper.contains(<ListDetails />)).toBe(true);
    // expect(wrapper.contains(ListDetails)).toBe(true);

    // expect(wrapper.find(<ListDetails />).exists()).toBe(true);
    // expect(wrapper.find(ListDetails).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
```

As you can see I've been able to test the toggleMethod with a given index and test if the conditions are true but not if the ListDetails component is being shown or rendered after that.

**A sample of my Vue component**

```
<template>
    <div
      v-for="(errand, index) in errands"
      :key="index"
    >
      <div
        :data-test="`errand-row-${index}`"
        class="flex-table__row"
        :class="{ 'flex-table__row--closed': index !== currentIndex }"
        @click="toggleExpanded(index)"
      >
      <ListDetails
        v-if="currentIndex >= 0 && currentIndex === index"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ListDetails from "./ListDetails.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    ListDetails: ListDetails
  },
  props: {
    errands: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => {
        return [];
      }
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentIndex: -1,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleExpanded: function(index) {
      this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex === index ? -1 : index;
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

I hope I'm making myself clear, otherwise just ask!

Thanks beforehand,
Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue seemed to be that I had to put

```
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
```

Before

```
expect(wrapper.find(ListDetails).exists()).toBe(true);
```

To wait until Vue has performed updates after you set a reactive property.

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html

Answer (score 1):

Your first test returns false because you don't pass any props so errands array is empty.

In the second I don't know what *selectedErrand* is.

Comment: Oh yeah so selectedErrand is currentIndex, I updated that. So you're saying I need to pass const wrapper = shallowMount(ErrandsListTable, {
      propsData: {
        errands: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }]
      }
    }); Or how would those props look? The text above doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think I found what the problem was. When I was triggering the event I didn't wait for the dom to update await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(wrapper.find(ErrandsListDetails).exists()).toBe(true);